# FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Bad Request ]

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

Calling

```
final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
```

results in

```
com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Bad Request ]
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeaw.zzaw(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdzu.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzebh.zzax(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzebk.onFailure(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeay.onTransact(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```

1. OAuth 2.0: I do have correct `SHA-1` in Google developer console as well as Firebase console.
2. I do have an up-to-date `google-services.json` file included in project.

Comment: Try to re-sync your gradle

Comment: Did you solve this?